# My laptop is getting hotter with ubuntu

Tags: power-management, laptop, heat

I installed ubuntu 16.10 in my Toshiba Laptop. Now I am realizing that the battery life has decreased and my laptop gets very hot now. What are the possible things I can do to reduce this?

Comment: Does your laptop have hybrid graphics?

Comment: I dont know what a hybrid graphics mean, but my laptop has AMD graphics card. thats all I know :(

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the model number of the computer and it's specifications?

Comment: Also please open the terminal run top and post key screenshots here. You'll see what's eating your CPU and MEM.